# What the components connects data lines to ground?

Tags: usb, components

I need to figure out what was the tiny components was connecting data lines to ground on board of a tablet.

Trying to attempt replacing Micro USB port on Amazon Fire HD 8 7'th generation (2017), I accidentely wiped some components from the board (red rectangulars on photo). Far left and far right pads within highlighted area of photo is ground.

[image: My board with wiped components]

Schematics for this board is unavailable as well as donor boards in my country.

This is the best close up board view I've found, components are marked with letter P i believe, and it looks like they have polarity, because "P" is upside down on one of them.
[image: Closest look at the board I've found on youtube]

Trying to google it, I find out that those components could be filters or fuzes, protecting data lines of overcurrent. Unfortunately due to lack of expirience and knowledge this is all I understood.

I hope somebody could help me to figure out what could it be.

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They were likely TVS diodes for protecting the data wires from ESD.

Replace them with any similar size USB protection component, maybe from some different donor board.